# Security of randomized data dependant key schedules?

Tags: block-cipher, algorithm-design, key-schedule

An example to demonstrate the point with two Feistel networks:

Cipher A:
\begin{align}
roundkey = hash(key || counter)\\
roundkey = hash(key || roundkey)\\
left = left\oplus hash(roundkey || right)\\
... swap\ and\ continue
\end{align}

Cipher B:
\begin{align}
roundkey = hash(key || counter || right)\\
roundkey = hash(key || roundkey)\\
left = left\oplus hash(roundkey || right)\\
...swap\ and\ continue
\end{align}

In the above, Cipher A would produce identical round keys during every encryption/decryption, while the round keys in Cipher B would be different for each set of plaintext/ciphertext pairs.

Do key schedules which incorporate plaintext data to generate randomized round keys offer any particular benefits or complaints compared to key schedules which produce the same round key regardless of the data being operated upon?

I understand that incorporating plaintext data might potentially allow an adversary to influence the key schedule, but the extent of which that is a problem probably depends on the specifics of the algorithm in question. I'm more interested about the general case, if there's anything that can be said about it. I'm also interested in whether or not it could complicate statistical side channel attacks like differential power analysis.

Are there many examples of randomized data dependent key schedules? Or better, papers outlining attacks against them? My search mostly turned up "data dependent rotations".

Comment: In a sense, both of your examples use the same key schedule -- in both ciphers the entire key can be characterized as an input into every round.  i.e. The round function is a function of the whole key, the right side of the data, and a round counter.  Cipher B is just a slightly more complicated round function, that involves the right side input twice instead of once.

Comment: @J.D. I agree with what you're saying, but wasn't really hoping to limit discussion based on the oversimplified example. Do you maybe have a better example that I/we might edit into the question to clarify the distinction? If it's clear enough what is being asked in the remainder of the body of the question, then the example could be removed entirely.

Comment: It appears to me that a "data-dependent key schedule" for a Feistel network could still be summarized as $left := left \oplus F( right, key, roundindex )$, for *some* function F.  If so, what is the fundamental difference between a "data-dependent key schedule" and a "data-independent one" (apart from the practical aspect that, with a data-independent one, an implementation may be able to do more of the key scheduling beforehand)?

Comment: @poncho Besides the fact that during each encryption run on different inputs the internal keys would be different, there is no difference. With a cipher like B the only key in common between E(M1) and E(M2) would be the initial master key. I would highlight the inability to do key scheduling beforehand as a complaint against the idea. Note I'm not suggesting this is necessarily a good idea, it's just a question I have as to how that one difference may or may not influence any attacks or the efficiency of the cipher.

Comment: Was a feistel network just a bad example? I just made the simplest example I could think of. If I knew of a cipher offhand that used the idea I would point to it; I was hoping maybe someone here might know one. Stream ciphers fit the idea somewhat, what with the seed generating a unique keystream. But I was thinking about block ciphers specifically.

Comment: @E.Rose - You may find it difficult to construct a SPN cipher with the kind of key schedule that you are thinking of - if you xor the entire state with a key that is dependent on the state the result is highly likely to be non-invertible.

Comment: @J.D. Right, a key element of doing this is that the entire block of data cannot be operated on at once. Otherwise it becomes a one way function. There are ways to do it (I have a toy that works), though it does not flow as cleanly as it does in a feistel network.

Comment: [this question is very similar](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18202/advantages-of-making-streamcipher-stream-depend-on-plaintext), though it addresses stream ciphers specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data-independent key schedules allow the round subkeys to be computed once in advance.  They can be reused for each subsequent block you encrypt.  This potentially allows significant performance speedups.

Data-dependent key schedules don't have that property.

Otherwise, there is no fundamental difference.

Normally, the key schedule is *defined* or understood to be the part of the cipher that depends only on the key and can be computed in advance (doesn't depend on the data).  So, "data-dependent key schedule" is somehow a contradiction in terms.